# Setting Kafka producer properties on AvroProducer in python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I am wondering how to add properties to an AvroProducer in python.

Here is code I have tried you can see something like i wish to do but adding in acks = all results in this error

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'acks'

```
avroProducer = AvroProducer(
{'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'schema.registry.url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8081'},
default_value_schema=value_schema, acks = "all")


avroProducer.produce(topic='test-topic', value=value,value_schema=value_schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

solution below

```
avroProducer = AvroProducer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'schema.registry.url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8081',
    'default.topic.config': {'acks': 'all'}},
    default_value_schema=value_schema)
```